# How to go from 40,000 triangle faces to about 5,000?

Tags: mesh, faces

Blender 2.79b
MacOS 10.14

How can I go from 40,000 triangles to about 5,000?
I send you my *.blend* file here:
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50544

I am looking for straight edge without mix edge like the example shown in the picture below.

From:
[image]

to:
[image]

Comment: The only solution in mind now is using Decimate modif. with an Unsubdivide settings for about 2-3 iterations - how it works for You? Another solution is select every other loopcut and disolve it. Doing it twice should give You a desired result.

Comment: In this question title there are two numbers: 40,000 and 5,000. Add those two together and you get 45,000. This was exactly the 45,000th question posted on the site. Either that is a crazy coincidence, or as a new user you already knew how the site worked. Either way, welcome!

Comment: Jan Matys, Did you check my document solve problem without mix edge?

Comment: X-27, No wrong answer You haven't check picture and show you Blender document

Comment: YES, and for sure DISOLVING the loopcuts will work without the mess.

Comment: This is the file after my edit... http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50560 ... It has about 5120 quads and the topo looks good imo. So next time try to follow the advice instead of insulting someone - it takes maybe 5mins to solve this. Your problem description is horrible not to mention that the images should be uploaded here directly so anyone could see what You want instead of clicking on and on. When You need something try to act like so...

Comment: Jan Matys, Text only I can't understand. Can you show me snapshot I will look up and how step by step.

Comment: I did not receive notification for a too long few months until I found this here oh that long time your answer. I am going send you pasteall link.

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51777
for Blender 2.80.